# How to selection sort a tuple in a list so that it sort the tuple in reverse alphabetical order without the use of sorted function

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, selection-sort

I'm having trouble at sorting a tuple manually so to speak sorting it in reverse alphabetical order without using the sorted() function
so far I have done this please feel free to correct me

```
names = [ ("Yoda", 0.455), ("Abbie", 0.66), ("Gigi", 0.5), ("Xena", 0.12), ("Champ", 0.3) ] 


def sorting_backward(names):
    for i in range(len(names)):
        min = i
        for j in range(i-1,len(names)):
            if names[j] < names[min]:
                min = j
    return names
```

so I want the output to be:  Yoda
                             Xena
                             Gigi
                             Champ

The reason that I want to avoid using the sorted() function is that I want to see if it's possible or not

Comment: I'm not familiar with this method of sorting. What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: I'm trying to sort it so the first string in each of the tuples are sorted reverse alphabetically

Comment: Your function does not do anything. Please clarify what you  are you trying to achieve. What is your expected outcome? Why do you want to avoid sorted? Why do you say you want to sort „a tuple“ when you actually have a list, and your code does not care about the element type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this will sort it from max to min

```
names = [ ("Yoda", 0.455), ("Abbie", 0.66), ("Gigi", 0.5), ("Xena", 0.12), ("Champ", 0.3)]
sort_list = []
while names:
    largest = max(names, key=lambda x: x[0])
    print (largest)
    sort_list.append(largest)
    names.pop(names.index(largest))

print(sort_list)
```